# suppress 500 errors in console after REST request

Tags: javascript, rest, sharepoint-online

I'm making multiple REST calls via Javascript to determine if a user is in several Sharepoint groups.

If the user is not in the group, the `REST` request returns a status of `500`, along with a message saying `"user cannot be found"`.

When an error is returned, I resolve my promise with `"false"`, so my function works ok.
But - every REST response of `500` puts an `error` entry in the Javascript console - is it possible to suppress those entries?

I know they don't impact the function, but it clutters up the console.

```
function IsUserInGroupNumber(permissionRequested,userEmail,groupNumber){
var deferred=$.Deferred();    
var url=L_Menu_BaseUrl+"/_api/web/sitegroups("+groupNumber+")/Users/getByEmail('"+userEmail+"')/Email";
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {                     
        XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json; odata=verbose");
    },                
    processData: false,
    success: function (data) 
    {            
        deferred.resolve({requestedPermission:permissionRequested,groupNumber:groupNumber,hasPermission:true});
    },
    error: function(data){         
        //user not found in the group returns a 500 error - but return value of 'false'
        deferred.resolve({requestedPermission:permissionRequested,groupNumber:groupNumber,hasPermission:false});
    }
});    
return deferred.promise();
}
```

Comment: Ultimately, the server should be fixed, because sending back a 500 in that situation isn't really appropriate. I think that most browsers will log any responses >= 400.

Comment: In this instance, I'm querying against SharePoint online, so I don't have any option of changing how the server responds. The response also includes message text indicating that the user was not found - so the server is accepting and processing the request, not just failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The service shouldn't respond with a 500 status code. That means something on the server is failing. You can't control how the JavaScript console / browser interprets and resolves an error or status.

Also, as of jQuery 1.5, `$.ajax` already returns a promise: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

You could simplify your code a great deal with something like:

```
function IsUserInGroupNumber(permissionRequested, userEmail, groupNumber){
  return new Promise(resolve, reject) {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: L_Menu_BaseUrl + "/_api/web/sitegroups(" + groupNumber + ")/Users/getByEmail('" + email + "')/Email",
      beforeSend: function (xhr) {                     
          xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json; odata=verbose");
      },                
      processData: false,
    })
    .done(function() {
      resolve(true)
    })
    .fail(function() {
      resolve(false)
    })
  }
```